# Usage of ELSE Conditional Statement in QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-3, conditional

I have an issue about how to change some data in a field not affecting unrelated data.

I want to replace '(space)' between words in **label_geo_** field data by this '_' sign when (if) this sign appears in another field - **label_eng** data.

So I tried to write this **WHEN CASE** (see below).

```
CASE
WHEN "label_eng" LIKE '%_%' THEN replace("label_geo_", ' ', '_')
ELSE ''
END
```

Unfortunately it changes all data in field **label_geo_** and replaces '(space)' by '_' everywhere in the field.

What should I write in **ELSE** to exclude all those data that do not have '_' sign in **label_eng** field and part of **label_geo_** data will stay untouched?

(Update for image)

I want to put '_' sign only there when **label_eng** data has it.

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what you want to do? Do you want to replace space by underscore `_` or the opposite?

Comment: I want to replace '(space)' only there where neighboring field data has the sing '_'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>You didn't specify a column to work on, thus your conditional reads as: 'if there's a `_` *anywhere* in **`label_en`**, replace all values in **`label_geo_`** (and in case no `_` can be found, replace all values with `(empty_string)`)' - note the last part!</s>

Try with

```
"label_geo_" = CASE "label_en" LIKE '%_%' THEN replace("label_geo_", ' ', '_') END
```

...there should be no need for an `ELSE` at all.

---

This became almost ridiculous...after you wrote it didn´t work I tried it myself, and the same thing in half a dozen varieties...nothing (btw., of course you are right with specifying the column, I was stupid here).

Now, what did work was this:

```
if (strpos("label_en", '_') > 0, replace("label_geo_", ' ', '_'), "label_geo_" )
```

or

```
CASE WHEN strpos("label_en", '_') > 0 THEN replace("label_geo_", ' ', '_') ELSE "label_geo_" END
```

The `LIKE/ILIKE` comparators return an integer (0,1) depending on the result, but I couldn't make `CASE` accept it on a per-row basis...

Comment: It didn't work, I got zeros (0) instead of any changed data.

Comment: In Qgis field calculator we specify column by function - "Update existing field".

Comment: @Vitruvius try it now, should work

Comment: That's it, it works. Thank you! But what do you think are there another ways? I don't know what "strpos" means is there any material to read about it?

Comment: @Vitruvius you can read about each functions/statements behaviour and usage in the field calculator itself! `strpos` returns the position of the first matching character or 0 if no match was found.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
CASE
WHEN "label_eng" LIKE '%_%' THEN replace("label_geo_", ' ', '_')
ELSE "label_geo_"
END
```

So if "label_eng" has an _ it will replace spaces with underscores in "label_geo_".

Else it will default to the original "label_geo_".

Comment: That hasn't worked. I've already tried.

Comment: What is the result of that? And why is it different to what you expect? That should work.

Comment: It adds `_` everywhere in the specified field.